# Heroku blocks bokeh.js scripts

Tags: django, heroku, bokeh

I have a problem wit heroku - after uploading my app which uses bokeh.js script, these scripts aren't loaded and I have to temporary turn off security in web browser. In this project I use Django.

Inspecting network:

[image]

Including script in html.file:

```
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

In addition when I run it on localhost it works fine. Did anybody have problem with that?

Comment: Does it work if you just remove the `http:` part from those links?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov it turns out it works when I remove it...

Comment: In general, https pages will not load and execute scripts from http urls.